# VS2010 Startup Crash, runs in safe mode, all add ins removed, still crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, startup, safe-mode

Suddenly my VS2010 crashes at startup. I followed other posts here, I removed ALL add ins, it still crashes. However it starts in safe mode. What else is disabled in safe mode what is NOT in the extensions window ? When I start with the log mode the last action in the log seemed to have completed correctly.

Any more ideas ?

```
<entry>
    <record>228</record>
    <time>2012/11/09 02:21:48.731</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{ED8979BC-B02F-4DA9-A667-D3256C36220A}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
    <record>229</record>
    <time>2012/11/09 02:21:48.735</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Visual Studio COM+ Library Manager Package]               </description>
<guid>{ED8979BC-B02F-4DA9-A667-D3256C36220A}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
    <record>230</record>
    <time>2012/11/09 02:21:48.737</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{ED8979BC-B02F-4DA9-A667-D3256C36220A}</guid>
    <path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\*\msenvui.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
    <record>231</record>
    <time>2012/11/09 02:21:48.739</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio COM+ Library Manager Package]</description>
<guid>{ED8979BC-B02F-4DA9-A667-D3256C36220A}</guid>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up Event Viewer immediately after VS crashes and look for Errors occurring as close as possible after VS crashed. The events should be under Windows Logs\Applications.

I'm currently having a problem with the same symptoms, and it is being caused by a stack overflow exception within VS. In my case, I have 2 sequential errors. The first is a .NET Runtime error showing the failing application, framework version, and description, stating that it's a stack overflow exception. The second error is an Application Error providing specific error codes and details for devenv.exe (Visual Studio).

Hopefully your logs will present more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate, and it was crashing all the time on start up.
(Windows 2008 Std SP2 32-bits, GB Ram virtual machine)

Like you, VS 2010 was working when launched in SafeMode

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE>**devEnv /SafeMode**

**After googling around, this was how I tracked down the problem.**

Go to directory where VS 2010 is installed and launch devEnv as follows:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE>**devEnv /Log**

This generates an **ActivityLog.xml** in

C:\Users\ user_folder \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

I looked at the ActivityLog.xml and the following entry was flagged with a warning

```
176 

Warning Component assembly is new or has been updated
          C:\Users\rickey.tom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Red Gate\.NET Reflector Visual Studio Extension\7.7.0.236\RedGate.Reflector.VsPackage.dll   

Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting
```

In my case, for some reason, there was a problem with a RedGate.Reflector component.

I went to the folder and removed the (Red Gate) extension

C:\Users\rickey.tom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions

And now VS 2010 Ultimate starts up.

This is just an example of how a problem is solved in the context of this component. 
I hope that this approach can help with other start-up problems.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've just lost two hours of my morning to an issue with VS2010 hanging on startup. I tried repairing the installation, safe mode, various other things, none of which worked. In the end I ran devenv.exe /resetsettings which fixed the issue really quickly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just have experienced the same problem on vs2010 and i have tried to open the project by using File>Open>Website and everything seems working fine. The cause may occur from deleting *.sln files which i prefer to keep them in solution folder rather than the same folder where the project resides. Hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved by:

1) go to path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
2)run

### devenv.exe.config

My problem resolved :)